# Center symbol in flash website?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I've been asked to help with a flash site:
http://tomix.110mb.com/
(Click on the center of the comics page)

The owner of the site wants to center a symbol in the middle of stage.

I am not familiar with Adobe Flash, only with AS3 and I suggested he'd use

```
symbol.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
```

I am not even sure he is using AS3.
He also asked where to put the script(I have no clue, I don't use Adobe Flash).

Please note you can scroll the site left and right so you can't just calculate x in advance. It has to move as you scroll the page.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `symbol` is already centered around it's own origin, you may need to modify your suggestion to:

`symbol.x = (stage.stageWidth - symbol.width) / 2;`

As for where to put this line of code, there's not enough info to give a decisive answer. Most likely, this line should come after `symbol` is instantiated. If the site resizes dynamically, then it should be inside the resize handler. If `symbol` is not instantiated programmatically, then it should be where ever the object placed on the stage with the instance name "symbol" is accessible.